# Error with getting current Location on my device

Tags: java, android, gps

I tried showing my current location in logcat in Android studio using Java but I don't get my current location on my physical or virtual device.
Here is the location it shows:-
Location: Location[gps *** hAcc=3 et=+11h30m2s390ms alt=926.5 vel=0.37214416 bear=190.44 vAcc=36 sAcc=1 bAcc=81 {Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=96]}]
The gps part shows ***.

My Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.userlocation">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.UserLocation">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My Main Activity

```
package com.example.userlocation;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    LocationManager locationManager;
    LocationListener locationListener;
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)     
        {
            if(  ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0 ,0 , locationListener);
        }


    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(@NonNull Location location) {
                Log.i("Location", location.toString());
            }
        };
        if(  ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
       
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},1);
        }else
        {
         
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0 ,0 , locationListener);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print location object in string form.
Try to use some method with location object tk get meaningful info